# How to sort by Total Sum calculated field in a Tablix

Tags: sql, t-sql, sum, ssrs-tablix

I have a Report in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 that has a tablix.  I have a list of Customers Sales grouped by Month.  I would like to add a grand total of all the Months for each customer.  I would then like to sort by descending amount of the grand total.  I have added the grand total, but I can't figure out how to sort on it.  Any suggestions?

Here is the initial dataset query:

```
SELECT
Customer, CustomerName, FiscalMonthNum, FiscalYear, SalesDlr
FROM
CustomerSalesDollars
WHERE
FiscalYear IN ('2013')
ORDER BY
SalesDlr DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with CSD as (
    select Customer, CustomerName, FiscalMonthNum, FiscalYear, SalesDlr
    from CustomerSalesDollars
    WHERE FiscalYear in ('2013')
), YearlyTotals as (
    select FiscalYear, Customer, CustomerName, SUM(SalesDlr) as YearlyTotal
    from CSD
    group by FiscalYear, Customer, CustomerName
)

select * from YearlyTotals
order by YearlyTotal desc
```

If you still want all the monthly breakdowns:

```
with CSD as (
    select Customer, CustomerName, FiscalMonthNum, FiscalYear, SalesDlr
    from CustomerSalesDollars
    WHERE FiscalYear in ('2013')
), YearlyTotals as (
    select FiscalYear, Customer, CustomerName, SUM(SalesDlr) as YearlyTotal
    from CSD
    group by FiscalYear, Customer, CustomerName
)

select CSD.*, YT.YearlyTotal from YearlyTotals YT
join CSD on CSD.FiscalYear = YT.FiscalYear
and CSD.Customer = YT.Customer
and CSD.CustomerName = YT.CustomerName
order by YearlyTotal desc, CSD.SalesDlr desc
```

Comment: I do not have a query that gets the Grand Total.  I created a calculated field for that data in the tablix.

Comment: @tsqln00b feel free to substitute the name of your calculated field where the sum is. If you can give me your existing query, I can better show you how to sort it.

Comment: I still need to know how to sort by YearlyTotal in the actual Tablix.

Comment: @tsqln00b Sorry about that. I had thought this was more of a SQL question. I am not very familiar with Tablix. Good luck with that.

Comment: Yeah, it sorts okay when I run it in SSMS, but I am still having a problem sorting in the Tablix.

Comment: I was able to get the proper sorting.  Thanks for the query!